# Programmatically create a multipage pdf document with multiple plots

Tags: plot, pdf-generation, gnuplot

I am trying to create a pdf file with multiple pages using **gnuplot**. Each page contains 4 plots of 4 different variables from a matrix. The following code works fine, if there are only 4 variables, but produces only one page, so the fifth variable gets plotted on top of the first.

```
set terminal pdf
set output 'plots.pdf'

set multiplot layout 2,2
do for [i=2:ncol] {
    plot dataset using 1:i with lines
}
set nomultiplot
```

The constraint is that I don't know in advance how many variables there are (ie, the value of `ncol`) and the script must be as generic and flexible as possible. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Where do you define the variables `dataset` and `ncol`? So, from your description I assume you have a file which has an unknown number of columns and you want to plot the data of all columns with 4 plots on each page in a 2x2 layout, correct?

Comment: @theozh That's correct there is a datafile read in and ncol is determined after that. I just posted the snippet of the code that is related to the plotting.

Comment: So, problem solved? Question answered? Any response appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @theozh for the suggestion, which works.
I found that a more straightforward, if perhaps less elegant (IMHO), solution can be obtained using an `if` statement, as follows:

```
set multiplot layout 2,2
j = 1
do for [i=2:ncol] {
    plot dataset using 1:i with lines
    if (j == 4) {
        unset multiplot; set multiplot layout 2,2
        j = 1
    } else {
        j = j + 1
    }
}
unset multiplot
```

Comment: Yes, this is an option. You could also use the modulo operator to make it even shorter. I will add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need *two* loops: one **outside** and one **inside** the multiplot environment. The script can easily be adapted to different layouts.

Check the following example:

**Data:** `SO75836938.dat`

```
 1   1.1   2.1   3.1   4.1   5.1   6.1   7.1   8.1   9.1
 2   1.2   2.2   3.2   4.2   5.2   6.2   7.2   8.2   9.2
 3   1.3   2.3   3.3   4.3   5.3   6.3   7.3   8.3   9.3
 4   1.4   2.4   3.4   4.4   5.4   6.4   7.4   8.4   9.4
```

**Script:**

```
### multipage & multiplot PDF
reset session

FILE_IN  = "SO75836938.dat"
FILE_OUT = "SO75836938.pdf"

set terminal pdfcairo size 20cm, 14cm
set output FILE_OUT

stats FILE_IN u 0 nooutput   # get number of columns
ncol = STATS_columns-1
set key top left font ",36"

do for [p=0:(ncol-1)/4]  {    # integer division!
    set multiplot layout 2,2
        do for [col=p*4+2:p*4+5] {
            if (col<=ncol+1) {
                plot FILE_IN u 1:col w lp pt 7 lc col ti sprintf("Plot %d",col-1)
            }
        }
    unset multiplot
}
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:** (3 pages, screenshot from PDF viewer)

[image]

**Addition:**

After @point618's response... Yes, you can do it shorter, less confusing and easier to customize by using the modulo `%` operator. The following script will give the same result as above.

**Script:**

```
### multipage & multiplot PDF
reset session

FILE_IN  = "SO75836938.dat"
FILE_OUT = "SO75836938.pdf"

set terminal pdfcairo size 20cm, 14cm
set output FILE_OUT

stats FILE_IN u 0 nooutput   # get number of columns
nCols = STATS_columns
set key top left font ",36"

ROWS = 2    # rows    for multiplot
COLS = 2    # columns for multiplot
c    = 2    # starting column
do for [col=c:nCols]  {
    if ((col-c)%(ROWS*COLS)==0) { set multiplot layout ROWS,COLS }
    plot FILE_IN u 1:col w lp pt 7 lc col ti sprintf("Plot %d",col-1)
}
unset multiplot
set output
### end of script
```